# VB.net 2010 compatibility in Windows 7 - 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, compatibility, vb.net

I just installed Windows 7 Ultimate (64 bit). I was just going to install Visual Basic 2010. In the 'Read me' file of VB.net 2010 it says it is for x86.

My question is will it work in 64 bit? Other 32 bit programs work well in 64-bit system but don't know whether an IDE will work or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't it say that the IDE is 32-bit but the compiler is 64-bit (if configured for 64-bit)?
I didn't have problems with 32-bit VS on my x64 Windows 7 and I'm able to choose whether I want to compile for x86 architectures or x64 architectures.

Comment: no problem ;) Did my answer help you?

Comment: Just tested it out, Visual studio works perfect :D

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio will run just fine in 64 Bit. What you read just says there is not a 64 bit version of Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Basic Express, and all other versions of Visual Studio, will work just fine an a 64 bit install.  I'm not sure which part of the ReadMe you are referring to but what it's likely referring to is that Visual Studio is a 32 bit native program.  It doesn't have a 64 bit version but instead runs under the Windows WOW64 subsystem.